# How to reset or remove words from exclusion list (un-ignore them) in spell checker in Visual Studio 17.7.0 preview 1 (2022)

Tags: visual-studio-2022

The "spell checker" feature in Visual Studio 17.7.0 preview 1 shows these blue squiggly lines.

There I can choose "potential fixes" (after the seeing the SPELL: "..." information when hovering over the text.

What if I choose ignore that word specific word (`foobar` in the example), and I want to bring it back from the "ignored/excluded list". How can I do that?

Is there a specific editable dictionary file or settings file somewhere?

Is it possible to reset it entirely? Is it possible to unignore single words?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a word from Visual Studio 2022's Spell Checker dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001599/how-to-remove-a-word-from-visual-studio-2022s-spell-checker-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

After writing my question, I found it is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76001684/17562157), with the exception that in my version it is called "ignore" while in that post they are talking about "adding it" to the dictionary. Regardless, the answer solved my problem.